# How to add a product from one MenuViewController to CartViewController using button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a restaurant app with `MenuViewController`, `DetailViewController`( all the details about food chosen from `MenuViewController`) and `CartViewController`. Now in `DetailViewController` i got a button (add to cart), pressing on which i want the food from `DetailViewController` to pass (to add ) to the `CartViewController`. Please help guys! Any ideas on how one can handle it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Tell us what you have done, write the code, and if you're having problem with it then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question you can do somthing like this:

First add method `setFood` to your `CartViewController`:

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController {
    func setFood(food: Food) {
        // Here do with `food` somthing you want
    }
}
```

Second in your `DetailViewController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let cartViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? CartViewController {
        // food is your some object you need to transfare
        cartViewController.setFood(food)
    }
}
```

Or if you create your `CartViewController` without storyboard in button action method you can do this in your `DetailViewController`:

```
...
var cartViewController: CartViewController?
...
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    cartViewController = CartViewController()
    cartViewController.setFood(food)
    self(cartViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
...
```

Comment: Yeah bro, I actually was asking and looking to find an answer to this part of the code: // Here do with `food` somthing you want: I have a foods data stored here: let data = [
        [
            "name" : "SALMON DISH",
            "ingredients": "(salmon, lemon cucumber salt, asparagus)",
            "image" : "photo_item3",
            "price": "$25",
            "discount"  : "EVERY SUNDAY GET 20% OFF"
        ],and so on

Comment: how do i pass the name and thumbnail image of the food to the screen of cardViewController

Comment: @Amir If you have some elements on the screen (`UILabel` for example), and if `Food` object in this context is dictionary like you write, then you can simply do `label.text = food["name"]`. And when you pass data to `CartViewController` you need to do somthing like: `cartViewController.setFood(foods[index])` where `foods` is array of dictionary like you wright and `index` is index of element in this array

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two approaches:

1. (Longer but robust Approach) Using Core Data: Add a new `Product` object to `Cart` entity. In your CartViewController, use `NSFetchedResultsController` that will automatically receive changes made to the entity and update the view accordingly (keeping in mind that you're using the same managed object context)
2. (Simpler Approach) Using Delegates: Maintain a global array that will contain product elements. Add or remove elements from that array. Keep a delegate function like `didUpdateCart` that notifies your CartViewController to update it's view with the current elements in the global products array.

Hope that helped.